# Difference between iterate and repeatedly applying a function

Tags: clojure

I'm studying the Clojure Koans:

https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans/blob/master/src/koans/10_lazy_sequences.clj

I am stuck on this one:

```
"Iteration can be used for repetition"
  (= (repeat 100 :foo)
     (take 100 (iterate ___ :foo)))
```

I don't know the exact builtin function to fill in the *_* blanks with, so I tried writing my own. I wrote it as a separate function as a test.

I intend this one to be: if x is a seq, then just repeat its first element. Otherwise, make it a seq.

```
(def f (fn [x] (if (seq? x) (cons (first x) x) (cons x '()))))
```

When I run it explicitly, it looks fine:

```
user=> (f :abc)
(:abc)
user=> (f (f :abc))
(:abc :abc)
user=> (f (f (f :abc)))
(:abc :abc :abc)
```

But using `iterate` adds an extra parenthesis:

```
user=> (take 1 (iterate f :abc))(:abc)
user=> (take 2 (iterate f :abc))
(:abc (:abc))
user=> (take 3 (iterate f :abc))
(:abc (:abc) (:abc :abc))

What causes this?
```

Comment: BTW, The exact builtin function is identity

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out the koan and looked at someone else's solution.

Comment: The koans don't always build your knowledge that well; I knew exactly the function I wanted, but because Clojure has so many built in concepts, I didn't know it was called identity until I came here!

Comment: The `keyword` function also happens to solves it for this specific case. Though that is just a side effect and `identity` is the "correct" answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-read the [documentation](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/iterate) for `iterate`:

> Returns a lazy sequence of x, (f x), (f (f x)) etc.

Use `nth` instead of `take` if you want the results of a particular iteration:

```
user=> (nth (iterate f :abc) 0)
:abc
user=> (nth (iterate f :abc) 1)
(:abc)
user=> (nth (iterate f :abc) 2)
(:abc :abc)
user=> (nth (iterate f :abc) 3)
(:abc :abc :abc)
```

Comment: Thanks. I got confused there.

Answer (score 9):

```
(fn [x] x)
```

solves this particular koan

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it with `#(keyword %)`

I've tried with `#( %)` but it doesn't work. Anyone knows why?

Comment: I solved it with just `keyword`.  I also tried `#(%)` first.  The issue is that the anonymous function still treats the first item in the form as a function so it ends up treating the :foo as a function with no arguments.  This works also `#(do %)`.

Comment: I've also been able to do it with #(-> %)

Comment: I later came across `identity`  which is part of clojure.core and returns whatever is passed to it.